# ¿como se hace en Unity para publicar una app en google play con la nueva norma de los 64-bit?

Tags: unity

he creado un app y no me deja publicarla debido a la nueva norma de los 64-bit y no se que cambios debo hacer en Unity para que la app sea compatible con los dispositivos de 64.bit y google me deje publicarla. Alguien me podría echar una mano? Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: Que versión tienes? Mientras puedes ir leyendo este articulo https://blogs.unity3d.com/es/2019/03/05/android-support-update-64-bit-and-app-bundles-backported-to-2017-4-lts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity admite x64 desde 2017 LTS. Para habilitarlo, puede ir a File > Build Settings > Player Settings.

Allí, en "Otras configuraciones", debe cambiar su Backend de secuencia de comandos a IL2CPP, y tendrá activada la casilla de verificación ARM64.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y luego puede seleccionar generar APK divididos por Target Architecture

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o en el cuadro de diálogo Configuración de compilación, elija Build App Bundle (Google Play).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que ayude, necesitarás tener el NDK de Android para esto.

Comment: Si, estuve mirando por internet y tengo todo eso ahora me falta el ndk, usaba uno cuando se permitían 32 bit pero ahora no se cual usar. Intenté descargarme otro pero al descomprimir el zip me daba error y no me dejaba extraer el zip entero, sabes a que se debe? O que ndk debería descargarme? Muchas gracias!!

Comment: te recomendaría si estás perdido, desinstalar los programas e instalar nuevamente siguiendo este tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8T75Aebl0U

Comment: Al desinstalar los programas, perdería los proyectos acabados o medio hacer?

Comment: La carpeta de los proyectos guardalo primeramente en un lugar, y después desinstalá todo. No recuerdo muy bien si se eliminaban los proyectos al desinstalar Unity

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, debería desinstalar también el sdk, ndk y jdk descargados anteriormente?

Comment: Tras haber hecho todo, me da problemas con el NDK, me dice que no lo encuentra. A que se puede deber y como lo soluciono? Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Guillermo hace el [tour]. Por favor entende y aprende como funciona la pagina. Si esta respuesta soluciono tu problema, aceptala. No agregues una respuesta diciendo gracias..